# Date from String incorrect

Tags: ios, swift, date

I copied an extension for Swift's `Date` object somewhere that allows me to initialize a `Date` from a string as follows:

```
extension Date {
    init(fromString: String) {
        let str = "\(fromString) 12:00"
        let dateStringFormatter = DateFormatter()
        dateStringFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm"
        dateStringFormatter.timeZone = NSTimeZone.default
        let d = dateStringFormatter.date(from: str)!
        self.init(timeInterval: 0, since: d)
    }
}
```

If, for instance, I pass `"2016-10-16"` as string for the custom initializer, the Date, when printed, should be `"2016-10-16 22:00:00 +0000"`, but right now it is: `"2016-10-15 22:00:00 +0000"`.

Any idea why?
Thanks!

Comment: Would who ever downvoted mind explaining why?

Comment: Why should it be `2016-10-16 22:00:00 +0000`? If your timezone is UTC+2, then midnight on the 16th is indeed 22:00 UTC the previous day.

Comment: Wait, so `hh:mm` takes the am/pm time, not 24hrs?

Comment: http://nsdateformatter.com/ @LinusG. check this

Comment: The official spec is here: http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-31/tr35-dates.html#Date_Format_Patterns hh is 12-hour format (1-12). What you want is HH (0-23) (and use 0:00, not 12:00)

Comment: Alright, that fixed it. Thanks! If you put that in an answer, I'll accept it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved the issue thanks to @jcaron.

#### Problem

The problem was that I mixed up 12 and 24 hour fomat when doing `"hh:mm"`. This is used for 12-hour formats while I wanted to use the 24-hour format.

#### Solution

To solve that, `"hh:mm"` needs to be changed to **`"HH:mm"`**